# GWT Element Event handling

Tags: gwt

How do I attach a simple click handler to a DOM element in GWT?

```
@UIField com.google.gwt.dom.client.AnchorElement anchor;
```

How would I create an onclick handler for 'anchor' ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10153663/1010868

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the [`ClickHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ClickHandler.html) interface, you can do this by wrapping the [`AnchorElement`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/AnchorElement.html) with an [`Anchor`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html), which has an [`addClickHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusWidget.html#addClickHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler%29) method and a [`wrap`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29) method.

So, for instance:

```
AnchorElement myAnchor;
Anchor anchorWrapper = Anchor.wrap(myAnchor);
anchorWrapper.addClickHandler(myClickHandler);
```

will do the trick.

This generally works for many of the UI elements:

- [Button](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29)
- [Image](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29)
- [TextBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBox.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29)
- [TextArea](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextArea.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29)
- [PasswordTextBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PasswordTextBox.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29)

But the wrap method is not an inherit from [`Widget`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html), so there are some exceptions:

- [CheckBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html) has no `wrap` method, but [`SimpleCheckBox`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimpleCheckBox.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29) does.
- [DateBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DateBox.html)